# Burning zeros instead of nodata in GDAL rasterize

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterization, raster-conversion

When rasterizing a vector layer I would like to achieve an output that contains 1 for areas covered by the shape and 0 for areas not covered. So far GDAL always converts areas that are not covered to nodata. I tried to change that with the following GDAL command but it does not work properly. I guess he burns nodata as zero but also the metainformation that zero = nodata so I cannot use the layer for raster algebra afterwards (all zells with nodata are excluded, however i'd like them to be zero in the algebra operation).

This is my gdal command:

```
gdal_rasterize -l GMW_clipped_2010 -a pxlval -tr 0.000269959 0.000269959 -init -999999999.0 -a_nodata 0.0 -te -94.9017777777779 10.918977291452409 -78.1278774106337 23.2768888888896 -ot Byte -of GTiff /home/GMW_clipped_2010.shp /tmp/processing_46ba07b600a54c5581ad63a22017470a/b2dc5cbedbf746a2b9dbbdb406bd35e8/OUTPUT.tif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifically telling gdal_rasterize to set 0 to nodata with the `-a_nodata 0.0` parameter you use.

You also specify `-init -999999999.0` which doesn't make much sense as your output type is `Byte` (and you only want 0s and 1s)

Try:

```
gdal_rasterize -init 0.0 etc...
```

Comment: And if you have many files already with nodata set in the metadata you can clean just the metadata with https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html by using `-unsetnodata`.

Comment: both worked. thanks guys!